# Issue with concurrent mic usage for an AI recording app, when using chrome/web browser

Tags: flutter, openai-whisper

I am having a hard time resolving this problem. My flutter web app uses AI to transcribe and analyze meetings. But the problem is when the live meeting is open in a google chrome tab and the flutter app is open in a different tab, it only transcribes the person sitting at the computer and not anyone in the meeting. It seems it is only receiving audio input from the outside and not any internal audio input. Is there a way to address this in flutter? Or is it not possible?
Thank you